# Cloud Firestore in Datastore Mode - Are sharded counters not going to be needed anymore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

The documentation states:

> Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode
>   uses Cloud Datastore system behavior but accesses Cloud Firestore's
>   storage layer, removing the following Cloud Datastore limitations:
>
> Eventual consistency, all Cloud Datastore queries become strongly
>   consistent.
>
> Transactions are no longer limited to 25 entity groups.
>
> Writes to an entity group are no longer limited to 1 per second.

My question is: Is there a new limit to how many times an entity group can be updated a second? Or is it supposedly infinite based on the above? Can't seem to find any more info.

Ultimately, I am wondering if sharded counters would still be needed for an entity like a "page views counter" that could potentially be updated 500+ times a second at peak times.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will still want [Sharded Counters](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/counters) in Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode for the same reason that Cloud Datastore benefits from them.

Comment: The reason you need sharded counters for datastore is because you CANNOT write more than once per second to an entity. If you can supposedly write more than once to an entity then sharded counters should not be needed. Your link is for Firestore in Native mode...

Comment: For Cloud Datastore, your limitation is 1 write per second for an entity group, where Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode, the limitation is 1 write per second per entity.  Entity groups may contain multiple entities.

Comment: @JimMorrison A single Entity is considered an Entity Group, no? So 1 write per second per entity or entity group means the same thing, no? Confused...

Comment: No, a single entity isn't strictly an entity group.  An entity could be in an entity group (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#entity_groups) along with other entities.

Comment: @JimMorrison So then, for Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode, what exactly is the improvement here? Could you give an example?

Comment: This question seem surprisingly similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52773542/cloud-firestore-in-datastore-mode-conversion-questions/52847078#52847078 .  Let me try for an example.

Given a hierarchy of kinds like: User / Friends / Messages.  So an entity in the User kind is the root of the entity group, then a friend of entity may have a key like "User/1/Friend/123", and a message from user 1 to friend 123, may have an entity with a key like "User/1/Friend/123/778".  With Cloud Datastore, all writes to any entity under "User/1" counts for the 1 write / second limit to that group.

Comment: With Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode, you can write to each entity in the entity group at 1 write per second.   To bring this back to shard counters, the sharded counter are each in their own entity group.  With Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode you could put all your counter shards in one part of your document hierarchy.